# Hello,I have 3 collections how to make a join to select the data with a single request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have three collections in mongodb i want to join them to get some datas.
this is my Schema:

```js
//user collection
{
    "_id": "616b429e0de99f6f74f911b9",
    "name": {
        "firstname": "Kisko",
        "lastName": "Barrisson"
    }
}
//Devices collection
{
    _id:"616b52453dcacbf8a3f989a8",
    user:"616b429e0de99f6f74f911b9",
    name:"driver",
    data:[{X:123,Y:200},{X:124,Y:300}]
}

//locations collection
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6193b7a7751212e5358b481a"
    },
    "X": 123,
    "Y":200,
    "adresse":"My current adresse"
}
```

I would like to do something like: `"Select l.adresse,d.name,u.name from user u LEFT JOIN devices d ON u._id=d.user LEFT JOIN locations l ON l.X = d.X AND L.Y=d.Y WHERE u._id=616b429e0de99f6f74f911b9"`.
How can i do that using mongoose.
Help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- start from devices, match the user
- unwind data
  (to make join easier, having the join fields inside arrays make things harder)
- join with users(SQL like join)
- join with locations

*you can avoid the replace roots, but they make the results of each stage looking simpler

*for performance make an index on devices.user, and on X,Y on the locations, also you need MongoDB 5, for index to be used in the second pipeline lookup

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pfARy-U20r7)

```js
devices.aggregate(
[{"$match": {"user": "616b429e0de99f6f74f911b9"}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$data"}},
  {"$lookup": 
    {"from": "users",
      "localField": "user",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "joined__"}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$joined__"}},
  {"$replaceRoot": 
    {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$joined__", "$$ROOT"]}}},
  {"$lookup": 
    {"from": "locations",
      "let": {"x": "$data.X", "y": "$data.Y"},
      "pipeline": 
      [{"$match": 
          {"$expr": 
            {"$and": [{"$eq": ["$$x", "$X"]}, {"$eq": ["$$y", "$Y"]}]}}}],
      "as": "joined"}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$joined"}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$joined", "$$ROOT"]}}},
  {"$group": 
    {"_id": "$user",
      "data": 
      {"$push": 
        {"adresse": "$adresse", "X": "$X", "Y": "$Y", "name": "$data.name"}},
      "userName": {"$first": "$name"}}}])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer I tried your two queries but it doesn't work with mongoose. I get an empty array. Please help me find a solution.

Comment: in the first i forgot to remove something before sending it to you, can you retry, with the new code(the second was ok) ?Mongoose allows MQL to be written directly, so you can use the code without any change.Can you also check the Match? in the above match is made with string, in your database you have ObjectId, so you will need something like `new ObjectID("616b429e0de99f6f74f911b9")`. If you can run it stage by stage to find when data become empty, if you find an example that query doesn't work, post it if you can

Comment: try run it also in mongo-shell so we are sure that its about mongoose, but i cant see a reason that mongoose causes the problem because it allows you to use the query without any change.

Comment: Hi thanks for the corrections. Some of the code is working. I'll give you the code that doesn't work. As soon as I add it I get an empty array:
        ` // {"$unwind": {"path": "$joined__"}}, {"$replaceRoot": 
          //   {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$joined__", "$$ROOT"]}}},
          // {"$project": {"joined__": 0}},
          // {"$project": {"adresse": 1, "deviceName": "$name", "userName": 1}}`

Comment: @Tekis for the id i do that for convert the id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("616b429e0de99f6f74f911b9").

Comment: if you have small sample data that the code doesn't work,send it if you can, for example on mongoplayground

Comment: locations collection:   {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6193b7a7751212e5358b481a"
    },
    "X": 123,
    "Y": 200,
    "adresse": "ffffffffff"
}

Comment: devices collection :  {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6193b7a7751212e5358b481a"
    },
    "data":[ {
        "X": 123,
        "Y": 200,name:"name data1"
    }, {
        "X": 124,
        "Y": 300,name:"name data2"
    }],"alarm":22,
    "user":"616b429e0de99f6f74f911b9"
}

Comment: user collection : {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "616b429e0de99f6f74f911b9"
    },
    "name": {
        "prenom": "Kisko",
        "nom": "Barrisson"
    },
    "created": {
        "$date": "2021-10-22T13:13:30.000Z"
    },
}

Comment: In mongoose i am using your code.

Comment: its not mongoose is the difference in schema, in new schema data don't have only X,Y but name field also, but its small change i updated them both. also in the new data there is no name in the devices, there is a new field "alarm". hope this time it helps

Comment: Hi yes it works very well. Thank you so much. But unfortunately I have the wrong data format in the result. I get: [{"_id":"616b429e0de99f6f74f911b9","adresse":"ffffffffff","userName":{"prenom":"Kisko","nom":"Barrisson"}}]. while I wanted the format: [{"_id":"616b429e0de99f6f74f911b9","data":[ { "X": 123, "Y": 200,name:"name data1",adresse:"adresse1 from locations" }, { "X": 124, "Y": 300,name:"name data2",adresse:"adresse2 from locations" }],"userName":{"prenom":"Kisko","nom":"Barrisson"}}].In summary the address must be added in data of the column of the devices collection.

Comment: Wow. that's some hideous looking code!

Comment: i deleted the previous queries, i kept only the one that i think its ok for what you need.

Comment: thank you so much. it works exactly as I wanted. You helped me a lot. I started using mongoDb a few days ago but the joining part of the collections is a problem for me I hope with the code you gave me I will understand step by step step how to make joins between different collections.If you have complete documentation on mongodb joins, you can send them to me. Thank you @Takis_